# removing image metadata from a buffer file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that downloads an image from URL

```
let imageBuffer = await rp.get({
            url: pictureUrl,
            encoding: null
        });
```

and i wanted to remove the image metadata from this file. Is it possible to remove the metadata without actually saving the buffer first into a file ?